# Fórmula de matriz (arrayformula) para numeración jerárquica de entrada de usuario tabuladas

Tags: array, revisión-de-código, google-hoja-de-cálculo, formulas

## Resumen

En un segundo intento se optó por usar columnas auxiliares procurando que todas ellas usen fórmulas de matriz para que posteriormente dichas fórmulas sean anidadas. Se logró obtener el resultado esperado pero de proceder a anidar las fórmulas de las columnas auxiliares resultaría en una fórmula demasiado compleja.

Por lo anterior agregué la etiqueta [revisión-de-código](/questions/tagged/revisi%c3%b3n-de-c%c3%b3digo). En específico el trabajo por hacer sería

1. simplificar las fórmula de las columnas auxiliares.
2. proponer una fórmula que no requiera hacer referencia a columnas auxiliares
3. comparar el desempeño de este enfoque con otros.

[Archivo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ezmZlDj-8XtbntgNZ7JPQjYMZWZTwJNAiUDl0-v3qOY/edit#gid=0)

Al final se incluyen las fórmulas.

## Escenario

Se requiere capturar una jerarquía de elementos en una hoja de cálculo de Google. Para ello, se están utilizando una columna para cada nivel como se muestra a continuación.

```
+---+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
|   |     A     |      B      |        C        |          D           |
+---+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| 1 | Elementos |             |                 |                      |
| 2 | Título 1  |             |                 |                      |
| 3 |           | Subtítulo 1 |                 |                      |
| 4 |           | Subtítulo 2 |                 |                      |
| 5 |           |             | Sub subtítulo 1 |                      |
| 6 |           |             |                 | Sub sub sub título 1 |
| 7 | Título 2  |             |                 |                      |
+---+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

A lo anterior se desea agregar de forma automática y mediante una fórmula de matriz la numeración jerárquica de los elementos.

El resultado esperado es similar a lo siguiente:

```
+---+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
|   |       A        |     B     |      C      |        D        |          E           |
+---+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| 1 | No. Jerárquica | Elementos |             |                 |                      |
| 2 | 1              | Título-1  |             |                 |                      |
| 3 | 1.1            |           | Subtítulo-1 |                 |                      |
| 4 | 1.2            |           | Subtítulo-2 |                 |                      |
| 5 | 1.2.1          |           |             | Sub-subtítulo-1 |                      |
| 6 | 1.2.1.1        |           |             |                 | Sub-sub-sub-título-1 |
| 7 | 2              | Título-2  |             |                 |                      |
+---+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

## Esfuerzos previos

### Intento 1

Se transformaron los datos de entrada en una tabla simple con la siguiente estructura

- nombre del elemento
- ID
- ID del padre

para aplicar una fórmula como la siguiente

```
=ArrayFormula(
   IFERROR(
      INDEX($D$2:$D,MATCH($C2,$B$2:$B,0))
        &"."
        &COUNTIF($C$2:$C2,C2),
      "1")
 )
```

Si bien es una fórmula de matriz no cumple con el objetivo porque

1. devuelve un único valor
2. No calcula correctamente el no. jerárquico de los elementos del primer nivel

```
+---+----------------------+----+----------+----------------+--------------------+
|   |          A           | B  |    C     |       D        |         E          |
+---+----------------------+----+----------+----------------+--------------------+
| 1 | Elemento             | ID | ID Padre | Formula matriz | Resultado esperado |
| 2 | Título-1             | 1  |          | 1              | 1                  |
| 3 | Subtítulo-1          | 2  | 1        | 1.1            | 1.1                |
| 4 | Subtítulo-2          | 3  | 1        | 1.2            | 1.2                |
| 5 | Sub-subtítulo-1      | 4  | 3        | 1.2.1          | 1.2.1              |
| 6 | Sub-sub-sub-título-1 | 5  | 4        | 1.2.1.1        | 1.2.1.1            |
| 7 | Título-2             | 6  |          | 1              | 2                  |
| 8 | Título-2             | 7  |          | 1              | 3                  |
+---+----------------------+----+----------+----------------+--------------------+
```

Al modificar los parámetros de entrada para que fueran devueltos múltiples valores, se encontró que COUNTIF no devuelve múltiples valores y el uso de otras alternativas no devuelven los resultados esperados.

## Intento 2

[image: Cálculo de numeración jerárquica]

**Observaciones**
- Para evitar tener que actualizar manualmente las referencias, se utilizan referencia abiertas (A:A), y la función MMULT
- Para reducir el tiempo de recálculo requerido, se eliminaron las filas en blanco. 
- Para prevenir que por "accidente" se agreguen automáticamente más filas de las requeridas se incluyó ARRAY_CONSTRAIN para limitar el número de filas.

### Columnas Auxiliares

#### ID

```
=ArrayFormula(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ROW(B4:B)-ROW(B3),MAX(IF(LEN(A4:D),ROW(A4:D),0))-1,1))
```

#### ID Padre

```
=ArrayFormula(
IFERROR(
hlookup(
MMULT(NOT(ISBLANK(A4:D))*{1,2,3,4},TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN(A4:D))))-1,
{1,2,3,4;{
vlookup(ROW(A4:A)-ROW(B3),{IF(LEN(A4:A)>0,ROW(A4:A)-ROW(B3),""),ROW(A4:A)-ROW(B3)},2),
vlookup(ROW(A4:A)-ROW(B3),{IF(LEN(B4:B)>0,ROW(A4:A)-ROW(B3),""),ROW(A4:A)-ROW(B3)},2),
vlookup(ROW(A4:A)-ROW(B3),{IF(LEN(C4:C)>0,ROW(A4:A)-ROW(B3),""),ROW(A4:A)-ROW(B3)},2),
vlookup(ROW(A4:A)-ROW(B3),{IF(LEN(D4:D)>0,ROW(A4:A)-ROW(B3),""),ROW(A4:A)-ROW(B3)},2)
}}
,ROW(A4:A)-ROW(B3),1),""))
```

#### Numeración por nivel jerárquico

Primer Nivel

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
vlookup(ROW(A4:A)-1,{IF(LEN(A4:A)>0,ROW(A4:A)-1,""),
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
MMULT((F4:F=TRANSPOSE(F4:F))*(COUNT(E4:E)-E4:E<TRANSPOSE(COUNT(E4:E)-E4:E)),
SIGN(ROW(E4:E)))+1,COUNTA(E4:E),1)},2),
MAX(IF(ISBLANK(A4:D),0,ROW(A4:D))),1),""))
```

Segundo a cuarto nivel

Se requieren tres columnas con prácticamente la misma fórmula. Sólo cambia la columnas a las que se hace referencia.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
vlookup(ROW(B4:B)-1,{IF(LEN(B4:B)>0,ROW(B4:B)-1,""),
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
MMULT((F4:F=TRANSPOSE(F4:F))*(COUNT(E4:E)-E4:E<TRANSPOSE(COUNT(E4:E)-E4:E)),
SIGN(ROW(E4:E)))+1
,COUNTA(E4:E),1),1/SIGN(LEN(A4:A))},2),
MAX(IF(ISBLANK($A$4:D),0,ROW($A$4:$D))),
1),""))
```

#### Nivel

```
=ArrayFormula(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
MMULT(NOT(ISBLANK(A4:D))*{1,2,3,4},TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN(A4:D)))),
MAX(IF(LEN(A4:D),ROW(A4:D),0))-1,1))
```

#### Resultado

```
=ArrayFormula(G4:G&IF(K4:K>=2,"."&H4:H,"")&IF(K4:K>=3,"."&I4:I,"")&IF(K4:K>=4,"."&J4:J,""))
```

Comment: Pregunta relacionada en el sitio en inglés: [Calculate hierarchical labels for Google Sheets using native functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711081/calculate-hierarchical-labels-for-google-sheets-using-native-functions/). En dicha pregunta publiqué una respuesta con el parte de lo descrito como intento previo.

Comment: Se realizó una mejora a las fórmulas en [Revisión 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rIz5cLlLi4CSZTF8iOIXPquTynm2sYDJO28WRTlRBqY/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mediante formulas no se me ocurre ni como plantearlo.

Con código lo haría de esta manera:

```
function AutoIndex(values)
{
  var res=[];
  var level = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

  for(var i = 0 ; i < values.length ; ++i)
  {
     var row = values[i];
     for(var j = 0 ; j < row.length  ; ++j)
     {
       if( row[j] != "" )
       {
         level[j]++;
         for(var k = j+1 ; k < level.length ; ++k )
         {
           level[k] = 0;
         }
       }
     }
    var tag = level[0];
    for(var j = 1 ; j < level.length ; ++j )
    {
       if ( level[j] != 0 )
       {
         tag += "." + level[j];
       } 
    }

    res.push(tag);
  }

  return res;
}
```

Ahora solo tocaría desde la hoja de cálculo hacer =AutoIndex( rango de datos )

Tengo que decir que el problema era bastante más complejo de lo que podría parecer en un principio. Es por ello que he hecho una entrada en mi blog. Como siempre, espero que no te moleste, he puesto link a tu perfil y a la pregunta: http://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/como-crear-numeracion-jerarquica-de-una.html

Comment: No es ninguna molestia, al contrario, me siento honrado. Me da mucho gusto que le des importancia al tema de las atribuciones. Nota: He votado positivamente porque el código que nos has compartido seguramente será de utilidad. Me reservo marcar como mejor respuesta porque la expectativa son aportaciones basadas principalmente en el uso de funciones incluidas (built-in functions). En otras palabras es más un ejercicio para profundizar en la comprensión de estas mas que que en las secuencias de comandos.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo... Este ejercicio en concreto parece tonto pero implica un curro acojonante. A ver si alguien encuenra una solución mejor.

Comment: Pues pasados los meses, siendo esta la única respuesta, la he aceptado.